# Install/Update RubyGems on Mac 10.5.8

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass-sass

I'm trying to update my Rubygems on a mac OSX 10.5.8. Currently running 1.0.1. I've downloaded v.8.24 from https://rubygems.org/pages/download .

As they say CD'd to the unzipped folder and than this came out:

```
macbook-10:~ sergehonderdos$ cd ~/Desktop/rubygems-1.8.24
macbook-10:rubygems-1.8.24 sergehonderdos$ sudo ruby setup.rb
Password:
./lib/rubygems.rb:335: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
./lib/rubygems.rb:517: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
./lib/rubygems.rb:32:in `require': ./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '|' (SyntaxError)
... define_method name do |*args, &block| # TODO: really works ...
                              ^
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting '}'
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting '}'
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting '}'
    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:32
    from setup.rb:27:in `require'
    from setup.rb:27
macbook-10:rubygems-1.8.24 sergehonderdos$ gem -v
1.0.1
```

The reason I try to update is to install compass.

I have no idea what went wrong, any solutions?

Comment: What version of ruby is installed? `ruby setup.rb` works for me with both 1.9.3 & 1.8.7 (installed with `rvm`). One possible solution might be to uninstall RUBYGEMS completely and try again. Ref: [Uninstalling RUBYGEMS](http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-May/038251.html)

Comment: macbook-10:~ sergehonderdos$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [universal-darwin9.0]
I have heard of RVM and that it's easier but I have no idea what it is...

Comment: OK; so it could be because of ruby version `1.8.6` (I will try to reproduce it later on after installing 1.8.6 version.) Any reason why you don't want to upgrade ruby version to 1.8.7? Or even better to 1.9.3? Also preferable to start using `rvm` so that you can have multiple versions of ruby installed. Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm?view=asciicast for some guidance on updating ruby & starting with rvm. [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/) is very helpful as well.

Comment: Great! I'm going to read my way true updating ruby. Actualy there is no reason for not updating other than not knowing it's there. I'm a regular webdesigner learning Front-End for just over a month and interested in Less/Sass.

Comment: Cool; I reproduced the behavior and posted an answer below. Another recommendation I have is to go through the first few chapters of the freely available [Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) to gain understanding of the tools and best practices in the ruby/rails world.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this behavior by installing `ruby 1.8.6` on my machine installed with `rvm`. Confirms that `rubygems 1.8.24` version is not compatible with `ruby 1.8.6` version.

There might be some way to install a previous version of rubygems which is compatible with 1.8.6., but I expect that to be a complicated task. Most ruby components would have moved ahead to be compatible with newer versions of ruby (either 1.8.7 or 1.9.3)

Best way to deal with this would be to upgrade the ruby version.